# XFeatures2D Android - Undefined Reference

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

Getting an undefined reference on the following line:

```
mSiftEx = xfeatures2d::SiftFeatureDetector::create(features, octaveLayers,
        contrastThreshold, edgeThreshold, sigma);
```

I am using a custom Android NDK makefile which is the following:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off
include /opt/opencv-android/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := /src/main/jni /usr/local/include
LOCAL_MODULE    := SIFT
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := mSIFT.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS    += -llog -std=c++11
LOCAL_LIBRARIES = -L/usr/local/lib \
    -lopencv_core \
    -lopencv_imgproc \
    -lopencv_highgui \
    -lopencv_ml \
    -lopencv_video \
    -lopencv_features2d \
    -lopencv_calib3d \
    -lopencv_objdetect \
    -lopencv_contrib \
    -lopencv_legacy \
    -lopencv_flann \
    -lopencv_xfeatures2d

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

If I add the following to LOCAL_LDLIBS:

```
-L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_xfeatures2d
```

It compiles, but errors on runtime with the following:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libopencv_xfeatures2d.so.3.1" not found

I am using OpenCV 3.1, on an x86_64 architecture for Android.

Comment: is `libopencv_xfeatures2d.so.3.1` in a folder where java can find it?

Comment: Well all my libraries are within /usr/local/lib and should be called from my Makefile. Not sure what else it could be?

Comment: xfeatures2d is the part of [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib). Have you compiled it?

Comment: Yes, it is compiled. Files are found in my /usr/local/lib directory along with includes in /usr/local/include